# Prove $F(n+2) - 1 = 1 + n(h-1) + n(h-2)$ by mathematical induction

Tags: graph-theory, computer-science, recursion, fibonacci-numbers, trees

$F(0)= 0$ and $F(1) = 1$ are predefined; $F(n)$ references the $n^{th}$ Fibonacci number. $n(h)$ is the minimal number of nodes needed to construct a AVL binary tree of height $h$. The theory shouldn't matter too much here I only have to prove the equation by complete induction. I am already through the induction hypothesis and tried two different values $> 2$ which worked fine as expected.

This is what I did:
After swapping $h$ with $k+1$ I got: 
$1 + n(h) + n(h-1) = F(h+3) - 1$

I then splitted $F(h+3) - 1$ into it's components $F(h+2) + F(h+1) - 1$.

Then $F(h+2) - 1$ could be replaced by $1 + n(h-1) + n(h-2)$ following the hypothesis.

This gets:
$1 + n(h) + n(h-1) = 1 + n(h-1) + n(h-2) + F(h+1)$ and this is where I am stuck as I could split the Fibonacci numbers as long as I want without getting any further. I would really appreciate some advice from you guys :/

Comment: What is $AVL$, and why would you (with reputation $6$) assume everyone knows this?

Comment: @DavidG.Stork: An AVL tree is a binary search tree that satisfies a particular balancing condition; there are insert/delete algorithms that maintain the balancing invariant together with the search tree property as the tree evolves. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/AVL_tree

Comment: But no, this should not be something a reader on this site is expected to know. @Xore, your proof probably ought to start by stating a recursion equation that holds for your $n(\cdot)$ function. It looks like you're trying to complete a proof without referring to any property of this function that you already know. That is pretty much a doomed approach.

Comment: @HenningMakholm If I were to define it further I would have to get further into the explanation what a AVL tree is. I can explain how I came up with 1 + n(h-1) + n(h-2): I will just state the facts without explaining further but if I look at a root node of a binary tree. One subtree must be 1 "deeper" than the other one. With deeper I mean that the height has to be higher by 1.

Now n(h) describes how many nodes there are with given height h. So the total number in such a tree has to be n(h-1)+n(h-2) + 1. Because we start calculating after the root we have to add the "+1" afterwards

Comment: @HenningMakholm The original question was that I had to prove following by complete induction: F(h+2) - 1 describes the minimal number of nodes required at given height h in an AVL Tree. The formula after the equation was given at some point in University so I assume it must be correct.

Comment: @DavidG.Stork I know there is a real lack of information but I assumed if someone knows a bit about Graph theory this knowledge should be required as it is one of the first topics. If I defined an AVL tree with all meta information included the question would be 90% background information I hope you understand that as everyone can inform themselves about AVL trees